# In Heroku, how I connect PostgreSQL from another server?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku

I created one App Python:Django in Heroku, in my settings I have a set up a database from Amazon WS, so when Deploy is finished, another configurations appear.

My settings.DATABASES

```
DATABASES = {  
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'myAppDb',
        'USER': 'UserAppDb',                     
        'PASSWORD': 'some_password',                 
        'HOST': 'myAppDb.cohkbwwvlbxi.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',                    
        'PORT': '7878',
    }
}
```

In console heroku I have this:

```
heroku run bash
python
from myapp import settings
setting.DATABASES
{'default': {'NAME': 'd7kqa751lkhqo6', 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 'HOST': 'ec2-74-75-228-85.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com', 'USER': 'hzhpegboxtikxk', 'PORT': 5432, 'PASSWORD': 'XfiPl1tJZB9Znk22b5UQmeYD2u', 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 500}}
```

In this case: `NAME`, `HOST`, `USER`, `PORT´,`PASSWORD` are tottaly diferent then I setup.

What I did wrong or didn't?

Comment: Heroku isn't doing this. You must not be using the settings file you think you are.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have two settings, one for server and another to local, in both don't have this configurations. But, is the same of ` settings.db_from_env` the code: `db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-writing the database with the values you get from `dj_database_url`. That is pulled from the environment variable that Heroku injects, `DATABASE_URL`. From your command line, run `heroku config` to see what it's set to - it will match what you see in your console session.

You can either 1) over-ride that variable (via `heroku config:set`) or 2) create a new variable (also via `heroku config:set`) and tell `dj_database_url` to use that variable, via `dj_database_url.config(env='MY_ENV_VAR')`.

Comment: indeed, in Heroku he set a `DATABASE_URL` with this param `postgres://USER:PASSWORD@SERVIDOR:PORT/NAME` I set my configurations. Thanks.